# Stateless object (no fields) - reuse or create new

Tags: java, object, seam, reusability

in my Seam webapp there is a service returning generators for document generation. These objects are without state (no fields), just methods. Is there anything wrong if there is only one instance of each generator inside the service and each request will return the same instance? Or should I always create and return a new instance?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're sure there's no state being preserved, I don't see a reason why you'd need to re-create it every time.

It'd be similar behavior to a [singleton-scoped bean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-singleton) in Spring

Comment: So new instances should only be created when they contain some state? Or are there any other guidelines worth mentioning?

Comment: @user - It depends on the context and what they're used for. Normally if something holds onto state internally, you really don't want to use it across multiple threads unless you're synchronizing things manually, which is sometimes difficult to do.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about Seam but it is something like an EJB underneath, isnt' it? In the EJB world there were stateless ejbs for exactly this case: (re)using objects without state.

So if that's possible with Seam and if those objects don't have state, make them kind of stateless beans. They can be then reused safely.

Re: static methods - that might work but depending on the design used at times you can't have static methods but need object instances, like where you want a certain creation flexibility by using factories.

Answer (score 0):

If the objects have absolutely no state then there is no problem with reusing them. However if they have absolutely no state why not make all the methods static and never create one at all?

EDIT:If this class is a means to pass functionality into a method, then I agree using static methods will not work. In that case then, all else being equal, I would recommend creating a new object purely to indicate to any readers that nothing is preserved between uses. However this is a weak preference, and if there is any other reason to reuse objects, go for it.

Comment: Sometimes one really needs to pass functions, and such a stateless class is a great way to do it in Java. One can "hard code" it with static methods, but it's not that easy to extend later.

Comment: It's because all the generators share common interface and are gathered in a hashmap which returns requested one based on string parameter - so that I can avoid if-else logic

Comment: If using some sort of IoC/DI container, then using non-static services usually is the norm. Services implement an interface and the actual implementation can be controlled via the framework configuration (e.g. Spring's resources.xml).